# Print a PDF file using PDFBox jar file

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to print a pdf file from java. I try many ways to print pdf but fail. At last, I found a solution in stackoverflow. But I try to run the below code but there is a problem when compile the code

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
Paper paper = new Paper();
paper.setSize(612.0, 832.0);
double margin = 10;
paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, paper.getWidth() - margin, paper.getHeight() - margin);
pf.setPaper(paper);
pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

// PDFBox

PDDocument doc=PDDocument.load(file);
job.setPageable(new PDPageable(doc, job));

job.setJobName("funciona?");

if(job.printDialog()){
    job.print();
}
```

There some problem occurs when I run the code. I give the error message in below

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.<clinit>(PDDocument.java:75)
    at Main.Create_Report_Card$4.actionPerformed(Create_Report_Card.java:419)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Add commons-logging jar into your project. If you are using mavenized project then add its dependency in pom.xml.

If you have to add commons-logging jar manually then make sure it's available in classpath.

For maven dependency, add following artifactId in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also you can search or download jar for latest versions from below URL:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/

Comment: I added apache commons-logging jar into my project. But this problem is not solve. So please tell me what can i do.

Comment: Is there jar entry exist in .classpath file?

Comment: yes, I add a sourche folder in my project then put the jar fileinto folder then add this in classpath

Comment: Which versions of PDFBOX and Apache commons-logging you are using?

Comment: @NahidHasan "but the problem is not solved" - don't forget to check whether the error you get is the same or a new one. And read the "dependencies" page on the PDFBox site. And mention what version of PDFBox you are using.

Comment: Thanks bro. Finally I success to print a pdf via java. Its so amazing.